# Same name (and signature) closure & function: non-ambiguous for >0 arguments, giving closure precedence when calling

Tags: swift, closures

#### Precedence rules for same name and signature function & closure

When defining a closure and a function with same name (say, `foo`) and signature, it seems as if the closure takes precedence when calling said (seemingly ambiguous) `foo`.

```
// Int -> () function
func foo(num: Int) { print("function \(num)")}

// Int -> () closure
let foo: (Int) -> () = { print("closure \($0)")}
/* or...
let foo = { (num: Int) in print("closure \(num)")} */

foo(1) // closure 1
```

If I option-click the two declarations, they point at each other under the label *Related declarations*, differing in how they are referred to as:

> Declaration: `func foo(num: Int)`
>
> Related Declarations: `foo`
>
> ...
>
> Declaration: `let foo: (Int) -> ()`
>
> Related Declarations: `foo(_:)`

If we attempt to define the same double-`foo` definitions for a zero-argument function & closure, we get a compile time error prompting invalid redeclaration

```
// () -> () function
func foo() { print("function")}

// () -> () closure
let foo: () -> () = { print("closure")}
/* or...
let foo = { () in print("closure")} */
    /* error: invalid redeclaration of 'foo' */
```

**Question:** Why is it that the first case above is considered non-ambiguous, and why does the closure take precedence over the function when calling `foo(..)` (i.e., in the overload resolution of `foo(...)`?

I haven't been able to find any official docs (or existing SO thread) explaining this.

---

Tested for Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3 and Swift 3.0-dev/IBM Sandbox (with function signature modified to `func foo(_ num: Int) { ... }`).

Comment: My *guess*  would be that the first example should be an error as well.

Comment: @MartinR Probably; I'll dig around Swift Jira and see if I can find some report on this.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you cannot name a variable and a function or closure the same thing if no parameters are passed. Although we call them in different ways (foo for a variable and foo() for a function. we will get an invalid redeclaration of foo. **The compiler treats the variable as if it has no parameters like the function does.** Consider some of these cases:

```
class X {
     var value : Int = 0
     func value() -> Int { return 1 }    // Invalid redeclaration of 'value()'
}
let x = X()
```

What is `x.value` in this case? Is it `Int` or is it `() -> Int?` It's legal and useful to treat the methods of classes as if they were closures.

What if we're even more tricky, and do this:

```
class X {
     let value: () -> Int = { 2 }
     func value() -> Int { return 1 }    // Invalid redeclaration of 'value()'
}
let x = X()
let v = x.value() // ????
```

Should Swift use the property `value` and then call it? Or should it call the method `value()?` **Closures are completely legal as properties.**

However, using parameters, you can name a function and a variable/Closure the same thing, although I would advise you not to. In this case you should try to name the variable and the function something that describes what they are and/or what they do to make your code more readable by others. I would suggest naming the variable something like

```
class X {    
    // Int -> () function
    func foo(number num: Int) { print("function \(num)")}

    // Int -> () closure
    let foo: (Int) -> () = { print("closure \($0)")}
}
```

because by naming the function it will allow user to know exactly which function your are calling **when your method and variable names are same.** user can know what parameter is for they are passing. by naming when you call the methods like below.

```
let x = X()
x.foo(number: 2)
x.foo(3)
```

and you **CMD** + **click** it will point you to the exact method or variable/closure you have written for.

consider previous example:

```
class X {    
    // Int -> () function
    func foo(number num: Int) { print("function \(num)")}

    // Int -> () closure
    let foo: (Int) -> () = { print("closure \($0)")}
}
let x = X()
x.foo(2)    // x.foo(num: Int)
x.foo(3)    // x.foo
```

Despite you called the correct method or closure. by **cmd** + **click** it will point you to the closure only.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I believe you describe more or less the points I have already posted as details in the qstion. I'm not interested in good naming conventions/practices, but in official sources as to _why_ we may name a function and closure the same, when they have the same signature (excluding those with no args), and most specifically, _why the closure is given precedence in the overload resolution_ of calling such a seemingly ambiguous closure/method name. (Note that in my example I have chosen with intent to let the function omit its external parameter name, to match the closure).