# Class have a variable name same as function name

Tags: swift

I have the following class in Swift 4:

```
class AClass {
    var add: (Int) -> Int {
        return {
            num in
            return num + 1
        }
    }

    func add(_ num: Int) -> Int {
        return num + 20
    }
}
```

Note that the variable and function have the same name 'add'.

Now in some other place I have this code:

```
let a = AClass()
print(a.add(1))
```

I have run this code, and the result is 2 (which means the variable's block is called).

So here are the questions:

1. Does the compiler always get the variable rather than call the function?
2. Is there any way to call the function?

Comment: Yes, it will always get the variable and there is no way to call the function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893524/same-name-and-signature-closure-function-non-ambiguous-for-0-arguments-gi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both the property and method share the same base name `add`, they have different *full* names. The method's full name is `add(_:)` due to the fact that it has a parameter (with no argument label), and the property's full name is just `add`. The fact that their full names differ is what allows them to overload each other.

If the method had no parameters, then the compiler would not have allowed the overload, as their full names are now both `add` and therefore conflict:

```
class AClass {
  var add: () -> Int {
    return {
      return 1
    }
  }

  func add() -> Int { // error: Invalid redeclaration of 'add()'
    return 2
  }
}
```

> Does the compiler always get the variable rather than call the function?

Assuming they have the same function type (such as in your example), then yes. There is an overload ranking rule that favours variables over functions:

> ```
>     // If the members agree on instance-ness, a property is better than a
>     // method (because a method is usually immediately invoked).
>     if (!decl1->isInstanceMember() && decl2->isInstanceMember())
>       score1 += weight;
>     else if (!decl2->isInstanceMember() && decl1->isInstanceMember())
>       score2 += weight;
>     else if (isa<VarDecl>(decl1) && isa<FuncDecl>(decl2))
>       score1 += weight;
>     else if (isa<VarDecl>(decl2) && isa<FuncDecl>(decl1))
>       score2 += weight;
> ```
>
> **<sup>[lib/Sema/CSRanking.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/baf2e4e6f6d8b5f18db33debef9424b130dcf97e/lib/Sema/CSRanking.cpp#L966-L975)</sup>**

In order to call the method, you can use refer to it by its full name, for example:

```
let a = AClass()
print(a.add(_:)(1)) // 21
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, [instance methods are curried functions](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/). Which means your `add` method is actually

```swift
static func add(_ self: AClass) -> (Int) -> Int
```

This is why the property gets chosen over the function. Calling `AClass.add(a)(1)` yelds the expected result, the function gets called.

Now, why does the compiler allows this name clashing if the first place? I'm not sure, but I assume it has to do with the fully qualified name of those two entities. The property is simply `add`, while the function is `add(_:)`.

Answer (score 0):

change the definition of your method to this:

```
func add(num: Int) -> Int {
    return num + 20
}
```

notice, I removed the `_`
this will force you to call the method this way `add(num:)` thus, you will be able to distinguish between a method call and a variable initialization.

for your question 1.) what you actually claim to be a variable is actually a closure.

Answer (score 0):

You raise a very interesting question about Swift's parsing behavior. I believe the correct answer is *it's undefined behavior*. `add(1)` means either applying the closure stored in the variable `add` or execute the function `add`. Both have the same signature and the parser / runtime library just happen to choose the first interpretation. I couldn't find any documentation on the expected behavior here so I'm putting it under *undefined*.

But defined or not, we can all agree that this is a bad naming scheme. Programs that intentionally rely on compiler subtleties are best avoided. To separate the two, remove the underscore in your function:

```
class AClass {
    var add: (Int) -> Int {
        return {
            num in
            return num + 1
        }
    }

    func add(num: Int) -> Int {
        return num + 20
    }
}

let cls = AClass()
print(cls.add(1))      // 1
print(cls.add(num: 1)) // 21
```

Answer (score 0):

There we can not perform the variable and function or the closer with the same name.

We will need to remove the `_` sign. So that compiler can execute variable or function differentiate by the external name of a function parameter. Because underscore `_` is used to make the second or subsequent parameter's external name not appear when a method is called.

You will need to change the definition of your method as following

```
func add(num: Int) -> Int {
    return num + 20
}
```

**Use**

To execute the variable : `print(a.add(2))`

To execute the function : `print(a.add(num: 2))`

However, we can set what parameter is for they are passing by naming when you call the function/method like below.

```
func add(value num: Int) -> Int {
        return num + 20
}
```

**Use**

To execute the function : `print(a.add(value: 2))`

So that we can get result according to needs.

You can visit the following link to understand the behavior of the underscore in Swift language.

https://dmitripavlutin.com/useful-details-about-underscore-keyword-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Another way is

You can get to the function by referring to it by full name in this case…

```
let add = a.add(_:)
print(add(1))
```

…but that's not a good general answer.